# Simple open source PDF-editor for redacting

Tags: pdf-editor

I am looking for a PDF-editor with the following specs:

1. Import should not cause layout to change
2. Import multiple pages must work
3. Integrate well with Windows 10 (Drag a file from file manager to open, use dialog boxes for opening files that look familiar, CTRL-Z for undo)
4. Must be able to redact pages (remove text - not just hide it)

I have looked at:

- LibreOffice: OK: 2+3+4. Fails on 1.
- Inkscape Poppler import: OK: 1+3+4. Fails on 2.
- Inkscape Native import: OK: 2+3+4. Fails on 1.
- PDFedit (http://pdfedit.cz/): OK: 1+2+4. Fails on 3.
- Xournal++: OK: 1+2+3. Fails on 4.

So I am pretty much looking for LibreOffice with Poppler/Xournal++'s/PDFedit's import engine.

An online tool is not a solution because the redaction is done due to privacy concerns.